# Is it possible to send an HTTP request from actions on google 's projects using trivia(one of the templates)?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I created a quiz application that I can use at Google homes.
Actions created a quiz using templates trivia (one of the templates) in Google on google.
I want to send http request according to the number of correct answers.
Please advice me.

Comment: This is not a feature that is supported in the trivia template.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can we add a feature that send a signal to my servers by another method?

Answer (score 1):

The trivia template doesn't support this feature.

However, Google [open sourced](https://github.com/googlearchive/dialogflow-trivia-game-nodejs) the original version of trivia, and you're able to use the source to adapt it to your own needs. It uses the previous version of the library, but should still work.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I will try it!!